How can I analyze HighSpeed traces what on Proteus project file?
I designed a few PCB on Proteus what includes High-Speed signal traces(USB, Displayport, GigaEthernet etc.). I want to analyze that High-Speed Traces. I expect see some values like eye diagrams, differential impedance, length matching etc. How to way I must follow ? Or do you have any software for that analysis suggestion ?
